# Google one tap signing `intermediate_iframe_close_callback ` not working

Tags: jquery, google-api, google-signin, google-one-tap

I am using google one-tap sign on my website, I want to handle user close events(escape and close button) and want to show some google sign-in button.

I have tried to use `intermediate_iframe_close_callback` callback to handle the close event as per [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#intermediate_iframe_close_callback), but it's not working. Here is the code that I am using:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: process.env.analyticsConfig.googleOAuth.clientId,
  callback: handleGoogleOnetapResponse,
  context: 'signup',
  prompt_parent_id: prompt_parent_id,
  cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
  intermediate_iframe_close_callback: logBeforeClose
});
google.accounts.id.prompt();
```

Can you any one please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#intermediate_iframe_close_callback) you posted, it says:

> The `intermediate_iframe_close_callback` field takes effect only in intermediate iframe mode

It means the need to add intermediate Iframe Support JavaScript API as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/amp/intermediate-support-reference).
And Integrate One Tap via an Iframe as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/amp/intermediate-iframe).

---

Other option to be notified about closing google one tap might be done in the `prompt` callback:

```
google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
    if (notification.isSkippedMoment() && notification.getSkippedReason() === 'user_cancel') {
        // do fallback logic
    }
});
```

You can have a look at the prompt documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.prompt) for more functionalities.